# Extremely long if-or-or statement just feel wrong

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm sure this is wrong, but I can't think of a cleaner way to do this. I'm looping through a set of column to identify which column identifies the company name, the test is true if one of a large number of tests are true.

```
if (heading.ToLower().Contains("organisation") ||
            heading.ToLower().Contains("business") ||
            (heading.ToLower().StartsWith("address.") && heading.ToLower().EndsWith(".surname")) || // A and B
            heading.ToLower().Contains("name") && !(nextHeading.ToLower().Contains("organisation") || // A and not any of B
                                                    nextHeading.ToLower().Contains("company") ||
                                                    nextHeading.ToLower().Contains("firm")) ||
 .......This goes on FAR to long (e.g. A == B, but (C != D and E != F)
 { 
      test = true; 
 }
```

The way I've currently coded it smells wrong (code smell is a bad sign), but using if-elseif-elseif.... feels just as wrong.

Is there a pattern that I'm missing that can simplify this?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: For one, you could at least extract `heading.ToLower()` to a variable of its own, so that you don't have to repeat it. (Imagine you will want to change it to `ToLowerInvariant()` later on.)

Comment: it is not really answers your question, but it seems you have a kind of parser of text information. consider using DSL for this, your code could be really neat in this case

Comment: Also, Microsoft recommend using Upper Case http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Put this into a function, eg. "isCompanyName". This function can be easily commented and written in separate lines.

```
 if (heading.ToLower().Contains("organisation")
     return true;

 if (heading.ToLower().StartsWith("address.") &&
   heading.ToLower().EndsWith(".surname")))
     return true;
```

And so on. This allows to comment the separate cases and maybe explain what they are doing. It's also easy to modify. You can also put things like `heading.ToLower()` in a variable to save space.

Comment: Thanks. The code is already in a separate function, but repeating `ToLower()` is definitely a **face palm** moment.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, you are recalculating `heading.ToLower()` a million times.

Next, go with @Cygal's suggestion and separate the conditions into a method:

```
private bool HeadingIsMatch(string heading) {
    heading = heading.ToLower(); // Done once only.
    if(heading.Contains("organisation")) {
        return true;
    }
    if(heading.StartsWith("address.") && heading.EndsWith(".surname")) {
        return true;
    }
    // ...
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are domain rules and should not be validated against text.

I would recommend that you use a parser to build up a domain objects from the text and use those objects in your application.

I just did something like that in of my own applications recently.

Something like:

```
// will be parsed by the object
var name = new GroupId("WORLD_ORGNAME_F_M_E-SomeName");
```

which allows me to use:

```
if (name.AdministrationType == AdministrationType.Manual)
    //bla bla
```

A bonus is that you can never type anything wrong or use values that are not allowed (which is the case with strings)

Answer (score 1):

I might be tempted to extract these rules into a set of functions

```
private static IEnumerable<Func<string,bool>> Rules = new []
  {
     s => s.Contains("organisation"), // Some descriptive comment here
     s => s.Contains("business"),
     s => s.StartsWith("address.") && s.EndsWith(".surname"),
     s => s.Contains("name") && !(s.Contains("organisation") || s.Contains("company") ||s.Contains("firm"))
  };
```

Basically, everything that can be `or`'d together, and then use `.Any()`

```
  if( Rules.Any(r => r(heading.ToLower()) )
  {
     //Whatever
  }
```

Advantage of this for me would be readability, and ease of adding new rules. And it's easier to in-line a comment about each rule as per the first one above for illustration.